# How do I make docker compose reference a secret from a file in a non-relative path in Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Similar to [How do I configure a secret in docker compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011448/how-do-i-configure-a-secret-in-docker-compose) but I am trying to define my secret to read a file from my home directory rather than something relative to the project like

```yaml
secrets:
  mystuff:
    file: /c/Users/Me/.gradle/init.gradle
```

But it can't seem to find the file.

I also tried `/mnt/host/c/Users/Me/.gradle/init.gradle`